# scrapy-splash xpath selector works in shell but not with spider

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

**Problem:** 
I am using scrapy-splash to scrape a youtube video page. However it seems the xpath does not return any element, except for the `keywords` element. (xpath are all copied directly from Chrome)

**Things I've Tried:**
At first I thought it's because the page has not been fully loaded when parse gets called so I changed the wait argument for SplashRequest but it did not help. I also downloaded a copy of the html response from splash GUI (http://localhost:8050) and verified that the xpath/selectors all work well on the downloaded copy. Here I assumed that this html would be exactly what scrapy sees in parse so I couldn't make sense of why it wouldn't work inside scrapy script.

I also tried the scrapy shell and with it, everything works fine:
 `scrapy shell 'http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HOfTrhmIXIM&wait=2.0'`

Response:

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="container"]/h1/yt-formatted-string/text()').extract_first(default='')                                                 
Out[2]: 'Scraping, analyzing youtube channel data with python'
```

**Code:**
Here is my code:

```
class videoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "videoSpider"
start_urls = ["https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HOfTrhmIXIM"]

def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse, args={"wait":5})

def parse(self, response):
    item = YoutubeVideoItem()
    #print(response.text)
    item['keywords'] = response.xpath('/html/head/meta[@name="keywords"]/@content').extract_first(default='')
    item['title'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="container"]/h1/yt-formatted-string').extract_first(default='')
    item['category'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/yt-formatted-string/a').extract_first(default='')
    item['visualizations'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="count"]/yt-view-count-renderer/span[1]').extract_first(default='')
    item['publication_data'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="date"]/yt-formatted-string').extract_first(default='')
    yield item
```

Comment: FWIW those things are available from the browser context as ytplayer.config properties, or you can just parse them out of the main response.

Answer (score -2):

Apparently, you are missing the allowed_domains list above the start_urls

I hope i have helped

Comment: scrapy script can run without allowed_domains